# How to use value in 1 function in second function

Tags: javascript, function, onload

Im still pure beginner with programing. I have this function

```
window.onload = function () {
  currentWidth = window.innerWidth
  console.log(currentWidth)
}
```

This function shows me in console.log what is my window width when i reload the page.

Then i have little bit complicated function which return also function.

```
const resizeHandler = (function () {
  const isBig = () => window.innerWidth > 850
  let wasBig = isBig()
  return function handler(event) {
    //if (isBig() == wasBig) return; // no change
    if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
      $('.side-bar').removeClass('non-active')
      wasBig = true // future use
    } else {
      $('.side-bar').addClass('non-active')
      wasBig = false
    }
  }
})()
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler)
```

I have width value in variable called `currentWidth` I thought when i replace **window.innerWidth** by variable name `currentWidth` it's fine but it is not.

Is my logic correct or in javascript is "smater" way to do that please?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And what is the issue? Please elaborate.

Comment: resizeHandler returns a function. Did you mean to pass `resizeHandler()` to the event listener?

Comment: Consider whether you should abandon a JS solution entirely, and use `@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) {}` for a pure CSS solution

Comment: The second big function works fine but when i reload the page it doesn't get the value. I must change the width of window and then it works. So i need get the value of reloaded page immediately

Comment: So check it onload. Sounds like you're checking it before it's done loading.

Comment: Propably? I don't know This is second "app". I cant use pure CSS fot his because i have already some JS related to this. That why i want use JS for. Otherwise yes. I could use media and set something like `margin-left: -100%`

Answer (score 0):

Directly call the resize handler on page load as well.

```js
resizeHandler();
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
```

Comment: I don't understand why but it works. Could u add litte comment why? Please. Every information improve my knowledge :)

Comment: @PetrHasil This runs the function when the page loads (this is necessary as the resize event is not triggered when the page is first loaded). Then it adds the element listener for "resize" so the function is called each time the window's size changes.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside a function are function-scoped, that means they exist only inside that specific function.
Try:

```
var currentWidth;
window.onload = function () {
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth
}
```

So now you can replace `window.innerWidth` with `currentWidth`, as you asked.